Is it possible to have Crystal Reports sort and group two different columns at the same time?
For the sake of picking parts from a bin system more efficiently, I would like to make a report that sorts primarily by bin, while also grouping bins by the same part--even if that temporarily breaks the bin sort order. The result would look somewhat like this:
Part   Pick Qty   Bin   Bin Qty
----   --------   ---   -------
F      23         B1    50
A      8          B2    27
Q      11         B3    1
Q      -          B7    82
C      1          B5    19
P      3          B6    54

Notice that the bin order is broken by a grouped part, but then it continues with sorting the bins in order upon moving to the next part. Such a report would hopefully allow personnel to simply walk down a row of bins and pick parts they need as they pass each bin, but also easily spot when a part has multiple bins, which aren't always next to each other. Also the part grouping would be easier to spot and sum when grabbing the same part from multiple bins to meet the total required.
I guess another way of putting it is that I want to group by part and sort by bin, but I don't want to be forced to also sort by part, which is what Crystal does to groups.
